Where to read org-mode patch notes?
I am running latest stable org-mode (9.6.30) and I would like to see what was changed from the previous point release (9.6.29).
The only release notes that I could find were for the 9.6.0.
Is it just me or do they not describe changes for small point releases?

You can clone the source tree and use git commands to find out stuff like that. There are 319 commits betwen 9.6 and 9.6.30, 91 of which were part of 9.6.1 and another 50 were added for 9.6.2. From that point on, with a few exceptions, each release only has a handful of commits. If it would help, I can post the complete list as an answer, but that would be just a snapshot in time. Cloning the repo and learning how to use git log with a handful of options is likely to be more helpful in the long run.

I see.
I hoped that there would be some other way than searching through the commits.
